# Send data from controller to jquery after ajax in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Send data from controller to jquery after ajax in Magento 2

I using ajax send data to controller, how to send data return from controller to js, please help me

My js

```
jQuery("document").ready(function(){
    jQuery("input[name$='general[product_id]']").change(function() {
        var productId = jQuery("input[name$='general[product_id]']").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "index/index/searchnameproduct",
            dataType: 'json',
            type : 'post',
            data: {productId: productId},
            showLoader: true,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My controller

```
public function execute()
{
    // echo 1;exit; 
    $productId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('productId');
    // var_dump($productId);exit;
    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
    $resultJson->setData($productId);
    return $resultJson;
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

Comment: check your `exception.log` file in `var/log/` for actual error

Comment: the error would probably at bottom of the file

Comment: 404 not found ??

Comment: add form_key in your post data

Comment: use get instead of post, and check if it resolve your issue

Comment: controller url is wrong.